# Azure DevOps deploys FunctionApp "successfully", but no changes are made

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-function-app

so I've set up an Azure DevOps pipeline building a FunctionApp from GitHub. I've downloaded the code locally and made two changes but neither are in use on the deployed app

I added a string to the start of the responses from the given Function1 function, and I've set up a second (near identical) function called Function2

When I push the code I see that DevOps picks up the change, runs the tests, builds the project, and deploys it. I know the changes are coming through because my Repository link on the Deployment Center shows the changes I've made

Am I missing an obvious step? The only things I've changed in the sample project are the things I stated above

Thanks for any help given!

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple Azure function and create a pipeline with the default Function App pipeline Template. It worked all fine.

[image]

You can go to the Deployment Center to check if the Source Version(Commit hash) is the correct Commit you pushed to github. This will make sure the commit with the code changes is deployed to azure.

[image]

You can also go the download the build artifacts in azure devops pipeline to check if the changes are included.

You can go to Functions to check if the second Function2 shows up:

[image]